# How to transfer data from high-speed ADCs in MCUs?

Tags: microcontroller, data-acquisition

Some MCUs contain multiple high spped ADCs, e.g. [STM32F303](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32f303ze.pdf) has multiple 12 bit, 5 MSPS ADCs. Let’s say I am using just one of these to sample a signal. Because 12 bits will be represented/stored as 16 bits (two bytes), I need 16x5=80 Mbit/s transfer rate. Of course the internal flash will be full in less than a second, while USB full speed supports only 12 Mbit/s. Even QSPI supports a max. of 40 Mbit/s.

How, then, can this enormous data be transferred/stored?

Comment: Nowadays we use USB2.0 if not USB3.0. And have you considered the possibility that an MCU might not be the device to use for this application? And you would not write that to flash anyways even if you could. That's a good way to wear out your flash.

Comment: Please edit your question and detail (lots of text) exactly what you are trying to do and exactly why.

Comment: If you want to capture data at this rate and send it, and this microcontroller is able to capture it but not send it, then this is not the microcontroller for your project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point of these ADCs is not to transfer the data out of the micro.

It has a fast ADC with many channels so it can quickly scan several channels and sample each one with minimum delay between them. This is important if you want to sample related signals "at the same time", for example current and voltage, while using only one ADC. With a lower sample rate, there would be more delay between each channel. Likewise if you want to synchronize the ADC with the PWM peripherals, for example to sample the current when your MOSFET is turned on, then the ADC sampling time will set a minimum on-time. A faster ADC allows a lower minimum on-time, lower duty cycle, or higher PWM frequency.

So in a typical application using the ADC at a high sample rate, it would sample in bursts, then run some algorithm on the data, then repeat. The ADC wouldn't run all the time.

In these cases, ADC samples are stored in RAM via DMA, and they never leave the chip.

If you want to store a long stream of samples from a fast ADC, basically you need some SDRAM, so that's not the right micro. If you want to stream that to the PC, you need USB2 or USB3, so again, not the right micro.

Answer (score 1):

In complement to bobflu'x answer (your MCU is not made to be used as an analog recording device), some ideas as how to try to get the maximum amount of data out of it :

1. You have 12 bits numbers : if you are limited by transmission bandwidth, don't use 16 bits to transfert only 12 bits : just use 24 bits to store 2 numbers : you just reduced the required bandwidth by 25%
2. Do you need 12 bits resolution? If not, you can drop the least significan bits (nb : you can configure the ADC to give you 6,8,10 or 12 bits, or just drop the excessive bits in software)
3. Is your signal changing "slowly" compared to the sampling? If so, you can compress the signal. If you have a known uper limit of sample-to-sample variation (for example maximum 255 * least significan bit), then you can just send the difference on 8 bits (instead of 12 for the full number). If you have no such garantees, or if usually the difference is very small but sometimes big, then you can go for some more complicated compression technics that are not fixed size (nb : not sure if you get enough CPU speed to do those)

Combining those, you should be able to fit the 5MSamples/s into 40MB/s. However, I doubt the CPU will follow (if you use only step 2 with 8 bits, then you are exactly at 40MB/s : if it is possible to use DMA directly from ADC to QSPI, then you did it ; otherwise, I there is no way with only 72MHz CPU clock)

Comment: Complimentary to #2 is does the OP actually need 5Msps? We could chime in if the OP provided any information at all about the application.